# Select posts based on selected categories

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have following scenario:

- user selects couple categories
- user should see posts which belongs to these categories
- post belong to one or more categories

I setup the database like this:

```
users -> category_user <- categories

posts -> categoriy_post <- categories
```

I managed to accomplish this, but I had to find all ids from these tables to find relevant posts. I need to make it simpler because this approach is blocking some other actions I need to do. This is my code:

```
$categoryIds = Auth::user()->categories;
$ids = array();
$t = array_filter((array)$categoryIds);
if(!empty($t)){
    foreach ($categoryIds as $key => $value) {
        $ids[] = $value->id;
    }
}else{
    return View::make("main")
    ->with("posts", null)
    ->with("message", trans("front.noposts"))->with("option", "Latest");
}

$t = array_filter((array)$ids);

if(!empty($t)){
    $p = DB::table("category_post")->whereIn("category_id", $ids)->get();
}else{
    return View::make("main")
    ->with("posts", null)
    ->with("message", trans("front.noposts"))->with("option", "Latest");
}
$postsIds = array();
foreach ($p as $key => $value) {
    $postsIds[] = $value->post_id;
}

$t = array_filter((array)$postsIds);
if(!empty($t)){
    $postIds = array_unique($postsIds);
    $posts = Post::whereIn("id", $postsIds)
        ->where("published", "=", "1")
        ->where("approved", "=", "1")
        ->where("user_id", "!=", Auth::user()->id)
        ->orderBy("created_at", "desc")
        ->take(Config::get("settings.num_posts_per_page"))
        ->get();

    return View::make("main")
        ->with("posts", $posts)->with("option", "Latest");
}else{
    return View::make("main")
    ->with("posts", null)
    ->with("message", trans("front.noposts"))->with("option", "Latest");
}
```

How to do this properly without this bunch code?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that You want to select all posts, that are in the same categories, as the current user?

Comment: For example, user wants to read news about php and laravel, so user selects php and laravel as categories. Now I want to show posts which belongs to php and laravel categories.

Comment: So what about simple SQL query - `SELECT ... FROM posts AS p INNER JOIN category_post AS cp ON p.id = cp.id_post WHERE cp.id_category IN (10, 20, 30) AND p.published = 1 AND ...`?

Comment: Your query doesn't check which categories users wants to read, you just manually inserted category ids.

Comment: I supposed You were able to put them there - `'... IN ('.implode(',', $categoryIds).') ...'`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Can you show me how to run this query in Fluent or Eloquent, because I don't know how to do inner joins in Laravel

Comment: Or You can take those categories directly from the database from user records: `SELECT ... FROM posts AS p INNER JOIN category_post AS cp ON cp.id_post = p.id INNER JOIN categories AS c on c.id = cp.id_category INNER JOIN category_user AS cu ON cu.id_category = c.id WHERE cu.id_user = 123 AND p.published = 1 AND ...`

Comment: If You are able to ask me, You are able to ask Google, too :-) See - http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins

Comment: Hehe. I thought there is Eloquent way. Thanks for your help. Write this as answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is Eloquent way:

```
$userCategories = Auth::user()->categories()
        ->select('categories.id as id') // required to use lists on belongsToMany
        ->lists('id');

if (empty($userCategories)) // no categories, do what you need

$posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($userCategories) {
   $q->whereIn('categories.id', $userCategories);
})->
   ... // your constraints here
  ->get();

if (empty($posts)) {} // no posts

return View::make() ... // with posts
```

**Or even better with this clever trick:**

```
$posts = null;

Auth::user()->load(['categories.posts' => function ($q) use (&$posts) {
   $posts = $q->get();
}]);

if (empty($posts)) // no posts

return View... // with posts
```

Obviously, you can write `joins`, or even raw sql ;)

Comment: First method works, but second one gives me double posts

Comment: You mean duplicates? This is possible, just add unique:  `$q->get()->unique();` and it will be OK

Answer (score 1):

You can take those categories directly from the database from user records:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM posts AS p 
INNER JOIN category_post AS cp ON cp.id_post = p.id 
INNER JOIN categories AS c on c.id = cp.id_category 
INNER JOIN category_user AS cu ON cu.id_category = c.id 
WHERE cu.id_user = 123 AND p.published = 1 AND ...
```

Joins in Laravel can be achieved, see the documentation: [laravel.com/docs/queries#joins](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins) Maybe there is also an Eloquent way, I don't know, try searching :-)

Comment: Sorry but the other answer is way more better for me. Thank you for your help.